# Print multiple arrays with condition in foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i need to print the names of `$aSpelers` and `$aRugnummers` when array `$Posities` of the `$aSpelers` is 'verdediger'

So for example: 
Janmaat 7 Verdediger 
de Vrij 3 Verdediger

So the first value of the array doesnt has to print out because it's not a 'verdediger'

Here are the arrays i have to use

```
$aSpelers = array('Cilessen', 'Janmaat', 'de Vrij' , 'Vlaar', 'Blind', 'de Jong', 'Sneijder');
$aRugnummers = array(1, 7, 3, 2, 5,8, 10 );
$Posities = array('doel', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging','middenveld','middenveld');
```

I have to use a foreach loop this is what i have already

```
foreach()
{

}
```

Comment: Why you dont create only one array and using 3 different arrays?

Comment: Well, you weren't kidding when you said you only had a foreach.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a multidimensional array. This makes your `goal` (get it?) a lot easier.

```
$aSpelers = array(
    array(
        'naam' => 'Cilessen',
        'rugnummer' => '1',
        'positie' => 'doel',
    ),
    array(
        'naam' => 'Janmaat',
        'rugnummer' => '7',
        'positie' => 'verdediging',
    ),
    array(
        'naam' => 'de Vrij',
        'rugnummer' => '3',
        'positie' => 'verdediging',
    ),
    array(
        'naam' => 'Vlaar',
        'rugnummer' => '2',
        'positie' => 'verdediging',
    ),
    array(
        'naam' => 'Blind',
        'rugnummer' => '5',
        'positie' => 'verdediging',
    ),
    array(
        'naam' => 'de Jong',
        'rugnummer' => '8',
        'positie' => 'middenveld',
    ),
    array(
        'naam' => 'Sneijder',
        'rugnummer' => '10',
        'positie' => 'middenveld',
    ),
);

foreach ($aSpelers as $speler) {
    if ($speler['positie'] == 'verdediger') {
        echo $speler['naam'].' heeft rugnummer '.$speler['rugnummer'].' en speelt positie '.$speler['positie'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

That should do the job.

#### Edit

I added an `if` condition to check if the `speler` is a `verdediger` and only echo if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

All array contain same number of value so you can use for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($aSpelers); $i++) {
    if ($Posities[$i] == "verdediging") {// check condition to match Verdediger
        echo $aSpelers[$i] . " " . $aRugnummers[$i] . " " . $Posities[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this for foreach. change array as object and use

```
$object = (object) $Posities;
$i=0;
foreach($object as $cont){
    if($cont=="verdediging")
    echo  $aSpelers[$i]." - ".$aRugnummers[$i]." - ".$aRugnummers[$i]."<br>";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `key` as `$i`.